# Yaml properties cannot be read by spring boot

Tags: configuration, yaml, spring-batch

I wrote a spring batch application with database connection properties configured in src/main/resources folder.

The job configuration is as below:

```
@Import({DataSourceConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfig;
    ......
}
```

The DataSourceConfiguration class is as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DatabaseConfiguration.class)
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseConfiguration dbConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbConfiguration.getDriver());
        dataSource.setUrl(dbConfiguration.getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(dbConfiguration.getUser());
        dataSource.setPassword(dbConfiguration.getPassword());

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

The DatabaseConfiguration class is as below:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("jdbc")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    private String driver;
    private String url;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    //getter/setter methods
    ......
}
```

The application.yml file is as below:

```
jdbc:
    driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname'
    user: username
    password: password
```

When I run the spring batch, the exception shows that the properties are not read from yml file. I have followed documentation for the above configuration, and I have no clue what is missing. Please shed light on this. Thanks.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' 
must not be empty
at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:276)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:124)
at com.telus.workforcemgmt.batchcloud.configuration.DataSourceConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:28)
at com.telus.workforcemgmt.batchcloud.configuration.DataSourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e128c57.CGLIB$dataSource$4(<generated>)
at com.telus.workforcemgmt.batchcloud.configuration.DataSourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e128c57$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b7fd119a.invoke(<generated>)
```

Comment: I would change `driver` with `driverClassName` (and its corresponding getter/setter) in your `DatabaseConfiguration` class.

Answer (score 0):

Check your setter method name for 'driver' property in DatabaseConfiguration.java

Is it?

```
public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
```

Comment: I copied your Configuration code in my system. To reproduce the same error, I removed the setter. And it thrown the same exception that you got.

Comment: All the setters are correct, so the error should not be caused by the setter. @dhana1310, can you run successfully with the setters?

Comment: Yes, it is running successfully when i added the setters, with all your configuration files. For your reference, I have added a git branch https://github.com/dhana1310/ws_spring_batch/tree/forKGB . which is successfully executing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to retrieve properties by environment api, not sure why configuration properties binding does not work. The modified version is pasted below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

    return dataSource;
}
```